# scala - calling methods of objects using for, foreach loops

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
val br = new ListBuffer[Piece]

  for(i <- 10 to 550 by 65) {
    br += new Brick(Point(x = i, y = 20, w = widthB, h = heighB))
  }
```

And a method `draw(g, color)` for `Piece` class. Now I would like to know how I can call that `draw` method for each `Piece` in the `ListBuffer`. I am trying in this way but I don't get why it's not functional:

```
br.foreach(x => draw(g, orange))
```

Thanks for any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget specify object

```
br.foreach(x => x.draw(g, orange))
```

or

```
br.foreach(_.draw(g, orange))
```

Comment: I have to get `Piece` items from the `ListBuffer` one by one and to pass in a method that check if they overlap geometrically with other pieces, I have this code: `if(ball isOverlapping brickleFirstRow.foreach(f =>...))` and I don't know how to iterate in that way that the `ball` to be compared with each elements in `ListBuffer`. The `ball` and items in `ListBuffer` are of type `Piece`.

Comment: I found a version : `for(br <- brickleFirstRow) {if (ball isOverlapping br)}` let see now if it works as is needed. Thnx

Comment: There are few solutions depends of your requirements. 
`brickleFirstRow.filter(ball.isOverlapping)`, `brickleFirstRow.filter(ball.isOverlapping)` and so on. Check out scaladoc to learn more about `Seq` class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `val` means constant and `br` couldn't be reassigned 
(`br += X` is equal to `br = br + X`)

Second, you'd better to refuse mutable state of br, you really don't need it. Just map range of Int into list of Bricks.

```
val br = (10 to 550 by 65) map (i => new Brick(Point(x = i, y = 20, w = widthB, h = heighB)))
```

Third, try to refuse OOP style while writing scala code. Use case classes for data representation and functions with pattern matching for operations with data.
E.g. class `Brick` shouldn't have method `draw`. Better

```
case class Brick(p: Point) extends Piece

def draw(piece: Piece, color: Color): Unit = piece match {
   case Brick => //Some drawing rules
   case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
}
```

And then foreach will look like

```
br.foreach(item => draw(item, orange))
```

Comment: The first statement about `br += X` always desugaring to `br = br + X` is wrong. `ListBuffer` actually has a method called `+=`. Therefore, `br += X` desugars to `br.+=(X)`.

Comment: About `val`-s, I am using a mutable `ListBuffer` thus the elements on it are mutable and I can use `br += X`. Thankssss for suggestion using `map`. About `draw` method I have it defined in `Piece` because I have to had it there until I inherit `Piece` class from multiple other classes, thus I am avoiding defining it along each one. Thanks @hellraiser